# How to prevent edit text to stretch over the constraint layout?

Tags: android, xml

I limit the constraint layout height to 250 dp, and when it get to the limit i want the the edit text open a scroller. But in the layout inspector i see that the edit text strech over the layout.

I limit the top of the edit text to parent and the bottom to some imageview.

How to prevent edit text to stretch over the constraint layout?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="250dp">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="write a comment..."
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:scrollIndicators="right"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/resize"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/camera_image"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/camera_image"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editText" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/camera_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/camera_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editText" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="POST"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/camera_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/camera_image" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/resize"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:maxHeight="200"` to your `EditText` and make it `wrap_content`.

This should do what you're trying to achieve.

Read more about this method here:[TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

(`TextView` is parent class of `EditText.`)